# Three.js how to apply a texture as material

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I just stumbled upon Three.js and I quite like it. I'm new to JavaScript but I would like to learn more about animation and such.

**//UPDATE**
I currently have this code, but it's not doing anything. If I try and do this without a custom texture then it renders a cube. So everything currently works except the texture.

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 500;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    var cubeTexture = new THREE.texture();
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();

    loader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        cubeTexture.image = event.content;
        cubeTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    });

    loader.load("crate.gif");

    var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(300, 300, 300);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: cubeTexture, overdraw: true });

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

}

function render() {
    camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have seen your error in the Console.

```
   var cubeTexture = new THREE.Texture();
```

Free tip: do this

```
   var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 300, 300, 300, 4, 4, 4 );
```

otherwise, with CanvasRenderer you will get a lot of distortion.

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much! It's almost working perfectly right now. Do you know if there is a way to "limit" how much the camera moves? I would like the effect to be more subtle, if that's possible. So that the camera only moves a little bit. I tried lowering the camera.position.x/.y variables in the render function but it only slows the movement down.

Comment: You need to accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark, and then, if you have additional problems, post a new question. But first, put some serious effort into trying to figure it out yourself. :-)

Comment: Well, I have tried. But seeing as the only thing I've ever done in JavaScript is some form validation and including the lack of documentation for Three.js can make it fairly difficult at times. Anyways, answer is now accepted, sorry for not doing so immediately.

Comment: Understood. The best way to learn is by studying the three.js examples and by experimenting with them.

Comment: And if you're looking for some examples, might I recommend http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/ ? </self-promotion>

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it correctly, you want to the image to stretch and move along with your mouse?
Why not use javascript for that?
You could easily read out the y & x positions of the mouse and then change the position of the image dynamically.
Correct me if i'm wrong, but if this is what you want, than I recommend using javascript.

Sincerly,
Harmen Brinkman.

Comment: I don't want the image to actually move. If you go to this site http://mrdoob.com/ with a browser that supports WebGL and move your mouse up and down, left and right. That's what I want to do but just with one image. There is also a similar example in the Three.js examples, http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_particles_waves.html

I just don't know where and how to start :/